# How do we calculate the average value of a field in a lookup relationship?

Tags: formula, validation, lookup, roll-up-summary

We have a lookup relationship between a meter (parent) and an index (child). We would like to calculate the average of all indexes, and then validate if the entered value of the index is not greater than twice the average of the existing indexes.

We were about to use a validation rule for this, but we don´t know how to get the average of the existing data. A rollup summary is not possible, because it is a lookup relationship.

Can anyone point me in de right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be faced with having to write a trigger here. "Summarising children from a lookup relationship" is a common developer problem, and I'm pretty sure it's typically defeated with a trigger on the child objects.

You'll need to stick a `before update`, `before insert` and `before delete` trigger on your index object, and use it to calculate a summary for all the sibling Indexes - average it - and update it onto the parent. It's the same function in both cases, but remember you need to cover all events. (its probably true that you need to consider `after undelete` as well actually, looking at my code for the last time I did this).

You can then use your validation rule to interrogate the parent value and check it is not half this new index value (I think that's your rule?!) luckily, I think the [order of execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) will support this as custom validation rules are re-run after `before triggers` are executed.

Whilst calculating an average is pretty simple mathematically.. It's a fairly complicated trigger, because you have to remember bulkification - including the fact that multiple indexes could come in from different meter (parents) - so you will have a couple of nice complicated `Maps<>` to traverse. Also remember hat multiple indexes could come in for the **same** meter (parent) - so you can't just load all the siblings via SOQL for a index and add them together for the average, as there may be other values "due" to be added in your trigger.new list... so there is some fun to be had merging the SOQL results with the trigger.new records!

Hopefully you are otherwise familiar with triggers (if not, [start reading here!](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_qs_HelloWorld.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)) and my advice above will help you avoid some of the mines that lie in front of you. If you are not familiar with triggers (or are working on Professional edition).. good luck!